# Will ISP see my router MAC address? connection by 4g USB modem

Tags: network, router, usb-drive, mac-address, 4g

Question is similar to [Will my USB modem send my MAC address to my ISP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32319/will-my-usb-modem-send-my-mac-address-to-my-isp) but not exacly.

I have router dwr-116 and usb 4G modem which is connected to this router.

Will ISP see dwr-116 mac address? or will ISP see only 4g modem IMEI ?

I think that ISP will see only 4g modem IMEI but maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: No they won’t but why do you ask?

Comment: @Sirens, thanks for your answer. I need to know this because I think about buy 2nd hand router which could be used to different activities.

Comment: your ISP will see your modem's ID, though, so it doesn't matter if they can or cannot see the router's MAC - everything is still tied to the modem

Answer (score 1):

No. ISP cant see MAC address of your router. MAC is a layer 2 address which exist within the network only.

And yes, your ISP will see only the IMEI.